# Restrictive selection in django-admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have 3 simple models in my Django project as below:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Location(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
      customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

class CustomerLocation(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
      location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
```

Now, I want to display the list of `location`(s) linked to a `Customer` in `CustomerLocation`  in Admin panel.

For e.g.,

```
Customer = C1, Location for C1 = L1, L2.
Customer = C2, Location for C2 = L3.
```

If I select `C1` as my `Customer`, I should be able choose only `L1, L2` in `Location`. Else, it should be empty.

How can I achieve this restriction in Django-Admin?

PS: I want to achieve this via `models.Admin` only.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pluggable django app for that: https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

You just add a field:

```
location = ChainedForeignKey(
    'Location',
    chained_field='customer',
    chained_model_field='customer',
    auto_choose=True,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)
```

(Not tested, but should work.)

And in Django admin, if you change `Customer`, `Locations` list changes accordingly.

---

*UPD.* Hm, it appears that I didn't understand your question properly.

1. What do you need `Customer` field in your `Location` model for? As far as I can see, `CustomerLocation` is responsible for linking these two models with one another, and every `Customer` may be thus linked to multiple `Locations`. You can achieve this with a `ManyToManyField` more easily, by the way.
2. Why do you need to display customers and locations at `CustomerLocation`? You probably can use Django filters for that. For example:

   ```
   class CustomerLocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ('customer', 'location')
       list_filter = ('location', 'customer')

   admin.register(CustomerLocation, CustomerLocationAdmin)
   ```

Then, you get:

1. A list of customers and locations
2. Two dropdowns for customer and location. You select particular customer or a particular location to get necessary data.

Will this solution work for you?

Comment: Thank you. But is there a way via the `queryset` option in my `models.Admin` class?

Comment: This helps in displaying along in the admin. What I need is restrictive selection in `Location` (during creating/updating). Like how the `django-smart-selects` achieves. I wan't it to appear in `models.Admin` class only.

Comment: In other words, when editing a `Location`, its `customer` field should display a list of those customers who are linked to this particular `Location` instance with a `CustomerLocation` instance, right?

Comment: Hehe.. The exact opposite of what you mentioned should happen! :D It should display list of `Location` for a selected `Customer`! You can see that `Location` is already mapped to `Customer` as a `ForeignKeyField`.

Comment: Hm, so, finally: you want to see a list of affiliated `Locations` while editing a `Customer`? And be able to edit/delete them?